# golang: *mongo.Database has no field or method CreateCollection

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to create a collection using mongodb's `CreateCollection`-method with the following source code:

```
package mongodb

import (
    "context"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

func CreateCollection() {
    var client, err = mongo.Connect(context.Background(), options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var db = client.Database("test")
    _ = db.CreateCollection(context.Background(), "Test")
}
```

However, I receive the error message:

```
$ go build CreateCollection.go
./CreateCollection.go:16:8: db.CreateCollection undefined (type *mongo.Database has no field or method CreateCollection)
```

Why does `Createcollection` not exist within `*mongo.Database`? The [documentation](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Database.CreateCollection) states differently. My IDE (Goland)  also suggests the method to exist. Removing and reinstalling all packages also did not change.

Furthermore, `options.CreateCollection()` and `options.CreateCollectionOptions` are undefined as well.

Versions:

- mongodb-driver: 1.3.4
- go: 1.14.4

Comment: The [documentation](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Database.CreateCollection) says *This method requires driver version 1.4.0 or higher.*  You are using 1.3.4. Go to https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.3.4/mongo?tab=doc for the 1.3.4 documentation.

Comment: I see. However, there is no version 1.4.0; I've run multiple times `go get -u`, and `go get -u o.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo@1.4.0` gives me: `go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo@1.4.0: go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo@1.4.0: invalid version: unknown revision 1.4.0`

Any suggestions on how to update?

Comment: Ah - a look at [github.com](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/releases) shows that 1.4.0 is currently in beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Muffin Top has pointed out, the `CreateCollection`-method requires `mongo-driver@1.4.0`.

However, `mongo-driver@1.4.0` has not been released yet and is currently in beta, which is why `go get -u` did not install it: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/releases